# remove write permissions from group developers

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a selfhosted Gitlab server and my user has admin permissions. There are two more users without admin permissions. I created a group "development" and assigned developer permissions to these users.

Next I created a private repository for this group.

[image]

The other two uses can see the project (which is the correct behaviour) but still can directly write to the repository (wrong behaviour). They can't commit to the master branch but their commit will create a new branch.

How can I create a repository members can see but they have to fork the repository and make pull requests to the original repository to make changes? So basically only me could commit to the master branch of this repository directly, because I am a project member.

A basic example would be big Open Source projects where just a bunch of core members could commit directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#project-members-permissions) documentation, you should change their permissions in the `development` group from `Developer` to `Reporter`.

Alternatively, you could also protect the `master` branch, so only you can push and merge into the `master` branch: [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#using-the-allowed-to-merge-and-allowed-to-push-settings). You can then allow the users to create other branches in the repository and submit merge requests into the repository for you to approve and merge.